# Wifi is not working after insatlling Open Suse

Tags: wireless-networking, gnome, opensuse, wifi-configuration, wifi-driver

I just installed the Opensuse 42.1 with gnome user interface. and I don't see any wifi logo in top right of screen.
In Yast -> Hardware Information, I can see my Network Card-> BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY and in Driver section of same page, Active=yes.
so knowing my driver, I installed the driver with sudo install_bcm43xx_firmware. but after a restart of system, it still doesn't work.

Comment: try broadcom sta drivers from packman repository

Comment: got the solution...i did the same... thank you